# Android - drawable with rounded corners at the top only

Tags: android, drawable, rounded-corners

I had this drawable to have a rounded rectangle as a background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/light_gray" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

This is working fine, as expected.

Now, I want to change this to only round the top corners, so I change it to this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/light_gray" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="6dp" android:topRightRadius="6dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

But now none of the corners are rounded and I get a plain rectangle.  What am I missing here?

Comment: This is really not a solution but I think I once had a similar problem. Increasing the stoke to 2 pixels helped, but you know, that's not a solution.

Comment: Here's an issue with shape corners: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=939

Answer (score 375, accepted):

Try giving these values:

```
 <corners android:topLeftRadius="6dp" android:topRightRadius="6dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"/>
```

Note that I have changed `0dp` to `0.1dp`.

EDIT: See **Aleks G** [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930555#comment11188211_8931327) below for a cleaner version

Comment: Exploring this further, I found an even better solution: `<corners android:radius="1dp" android:topLeftRadius="6dp" android:topRightRadius="6dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>` - this produces perfectly square bottom corners without even a hint of rounding.   However your solution pretty much works.

Comment: How to do it in code, given a bitmap? And how to add outline (AKA stroke) around it?

Comment: @Aleks G i don't see that it's necessary to specify `android:radius="1dp"`

Comment: @hmac it is necessary. Read the documentation, it makes it clear.

Comment: @AleksG Yeah the documentation is wrong, testing on Samsung 10, Android 9: "Every corner must (initially) be provided a corner radius greater than 1, or else no corners are rounded. If you want specific corners to not be rounded, a work-around is to use android:radius to set a default corner radius greater than 1, but then override" - not true, i specify bottom right, top right, top left as zero and bottom left +ve and bottom left is correctly curved

Comment: @hmac first note the date of the question. It was asked about Android 1.6 in January 2012. Second, without specifying radius, it worked on don't phones but not on many others. With it, it either on all devices I tested on.

Comment: @AleksG I'm sure you've noticed by now that your question is still relevant to this day. Would you consider editing the question and specifing which Android version it related to (I feel this would be much better than having readers infer this information from the date of posting)? Perhaps mentioning the device(s) it needed to work on could also be helpful to future readers. I would remove "Android" from the title as per modern SO standards for question tagging.

Answer (score 15):

Try to do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:bottom="-20dp" android:left="-20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It seems does not suitable to set different corner radius of rectangle. So you can use this hack.

Comment: See my own answer - it's perfectly acceptable to have different radius for different corners.

Comment: I tried this approach, it is not acceptable, ide tells that it does not appropriatr to have different rsdius and ignores it

Answer (score 15):

In my case below code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="10dp" android:bottom="-10dp"
        >

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/maincolor" />

            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
            />
        </shape>

    </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Top and bottom properties on the item are not needed unless you want a padding in the view, but otherwise this works.

Answer (score 14):

```
bg.xml
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="24dp" android:topRightRadius="24dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

**add in your layout:**

```
android:background="@drawable/bg"
```

Comment: If you read the question in full, you will notice that this doesn’t work and this is why the question was asked in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

Building upon [busylee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29472238/3372061), this is how you can make a `drawable` that only has one **un**rounded corner (top-left, in this example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <!-- A numeric value is specified in "radius" for demonstrative purposes only,
                  it should be @dimen/val_name -->
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- To keep the TOP-LEFT corner UNROUNDED set both OPPOSITE offsets (bottom+right): -->
    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:right="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Please note that the above `drawable` is **not** shown correctly in the Android Studio preview (2.0.0p7). To preview it anyway, create another view and use this as `android:background="@drawable/..."`.

Comment: @AleksG - Of course. It is relevant today as it was then (as evidence - I needed something like that). You must know that over the years some ways of doing things become deprecated and may need to be replaced with more modern ones. As **busylee** mentioned, the IDE complains when defining different corner radii, which is not the case with the present method. Moreover, since this question was my 1st hit on Google (iirc), it made sense for me to update it. Anyhow, I'm sure SO won't mind a few more KB of code... :)

Answer (score 9):

try to use `MaterialShapeDrawable` and configure it in kotlin/java code.

```
val backgroundShapeModel:ShapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel.builder()
    .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 16F.toPx)
    .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 16F.toPx)
    .build()
textView.background = MaterialShapeDrawable(backgroundShapeModel).apply {
    fillColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN)
}
```

[image]

#### P.S:

In addition to abilities that `xml` drawables provides (fillColor, stroke...), `MaterialShapeDrawable` supports:

1. `cornerFamily` in two category: `rounded` and `cut`
2. `edgeTreatment` with `TriangleEdgeTreatment`, `OffsetEdgeTreatment`, ...
3. doesn't need to context and getting resource

[image]]

```
val backgroundShapeModel = ShapeAppearanceModel.builder()
    .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 16F.toPx)
    .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.CUT, 16F.toPx)
    .setAllEdges(TriangleEdgeTreatment(5f.toPx, true))
    .build()
textView.background = MaterialShapeDrawable(backgroundShapeModel).apply {
    fillColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN)
    setStroke(2f.toPx,Color.RED)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and got a top rounded corner button. I gave the colors as `@ffffff` and stroke I gave `#C0C0C0`.

try

1. Giving android : bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp" instead of 0. if its not working
2. Check in what drawable and the emulator's resolution. I created a drawable folder under res and using it.  (hdpi, mdpi ldpi) the folder you have this XML. 
   this is my output.

[image]

Comment: What android version is this?  My app must run on 1.6 - and the emulator 1.6 had the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may need read this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

and below there is a Note.

Note Every corner must (initially) be provided a corner radius greater than 1, or else no corners are rounded. If you want specific corners to not be rounded, a work-around is to use android:radius to set a default corner radius greater than 1, but then override each and every corner with the values you really want, providing zero ("0dp") where you don't want rounded corners.

Answer (score 2):

**Create roung_top_corners.xml on drawable and copy the below code**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="22dp"
    android:topRightRadius="22dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    />
<gradient
    android:angle="180"
    android:startColor="#1d2b32"
    android:centerColor="#465059"
    android:endColor="#687079"
    android:type="linear" />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    /></shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing these attributes altogether.

```
android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
```