# Android drawable defined in xml

Tags: android, android-drawable

Is it possible to define a similiar rectangle like this:

```
 <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
                  <gradient
                    android:angle="270"
                    android:endColor="#444444"
                    android:startColor="#666666" />

            <corners android:radius="10dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

BUT ONLY the upper corners WITH radius, and the others without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cherck out this questions:

[Rounded corners only on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930555/android-drawable-with-rounded-corners-at-the-top-only)

This is the answer:

```
<corners android:radius="1dp" android:topLeftRadius="6dp" android:topRightRadius="6dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

Note that Eclipse chokes on this and will not display correctly in the view editor though,