# Android listview background

Tags: android, listview

I am implementing a list view like this for Android.

[image: beautiful list view]

Without worrying about selectors and the thin strip on the left of each item, the background layout drawable for list items would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="27dp"
        android:topRightRadius="27dp" />
</shape>
```

And I'm calling it `list_border.xml` and it resides in the drawable folder.

I have tried to set it as the background for the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_border"/>
```

and as the background for each list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_border" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow1_e" />

    <org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko.customui.MyanmarTextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the listview has not changed to reflect the new background. Is anything wrong with it?

Comment: The listview in AndroidStudio editor, or in your phone when you launch it?

Comment: Android emulator in Android studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For listview you are setting it for divider not background. Check it and rectify it

Comment: Yap. I just realized it and corrected it. Now it's running fine. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting the background of the relative layout to be the drawable with radius. Not sure how you named it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bakcground_with_radius" >
   ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `list_border` and I did try that. I want to radius to be on the right corners. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930555/android-drawable-with-rounded-corners-at-the-top-only