# Android - drawable with rounded corners at the top only not work below-v14

Tags: android, dialog, shapes, android-drawable

I am trying to make dialog with round corner button. but it's not working below **API_LEVEL14**

I am trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8931327/3778703) but there is no solution.
If you have any solution for below api-14 then share it.

for below API 14 it's show like

[image]

**and it's works well api level 14 and above**

[image]

for `right_below_corner.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="false"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/header_bg_disable" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/header_bg_disable" />
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/header_bg_press" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/header_bg_press" />
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/header_bg" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/header_bg" />
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

and for `bottom_left_corner.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/header_bg_press" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/header_bg_press" />
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/header_bg" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/header_bg" />
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp" />
        </shape></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: There is a workaround to achieve that. Add a view like `<View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/support_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />` which gives some extra gap at the bottom allowing the background to take a rounded corner

Comment: @AvinashChowdary i try this but not work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a bug in Android up until version 3.1. When specifying the corners separately, the bottom left and right corners get flipped:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9161

The only solution is to make separate xml-files for those 2 versions. Like this:

**res/drawable/corners.xml** – with the reversed values

**res/drawable-v12/corners.xml** – with the normal values