# Button with distinct corners and an Image at centre

Tags: android, xml, button, shapes

I need a button with left side rounded corners and right side flat corners.

complete rounded corners is possible with this code:

```
<corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topRightRadius="25dp"/>
```

Resultant image:

[image: done]

Now I need an image similar to following one:

[image]

I've tried the follwing code:(Sorry..This is an answer.But it was not reflecting in Xml)

```
<corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

But it is the not the correct one.

**To centre an image I tried the following code:**

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border2"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="50dp"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/facebook"   />
```

This fixed an image at centre.But is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Could you post image that you're getting?

Comment: sure @NikMyers ..just a minute.

Comment: oops..I got that..It was not reflecting in xml but reflected in device..

Comment: maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930555/android-drawable-with-rounded-corners-at-the-top-only

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps, you can use a 9-patch image.