# How to achieve the different corner radius for the CardView which is bottom right corner should have more radius than the other corners

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-cardview, material-components-android

[image]

I have tried using https://github.com/captain-miao/OptionRoundCardview this repo but it didn't help the cause as it was giving edged corners.

Comment: The above links answers only rounded corners and non rounded corners but my problem is to get the different radiuses for different corners.

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod Please help to expalin why its a duplicate question.

Comment: Check this ; https://stackoverflow.com/a/8931327/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod the above link can have the shape but need the elevation and shadow exactly as per the outline.

Comment: You can use the standard MaterialCardView with a simple style. Just check the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard [**`MaterialCard`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialCardView.md) included in the official [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Use in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        style="@style/MyCardView"
        ...>
```

In your style use the new [**`shapeAppearanceOverlay`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) attribute to customize the shape (It requires the version **1.1.0.**)

```
  <style name="MyCardView" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay_only_on_top</item>
  </style>
```

Something like:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialCardView.Cut" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">4dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">4dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: content not clipping.