# How to set background of an activity/fragment with color pattern/shape

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, background

I am developing an App.I want to set some shape with color for background of my activity. I am attaching sample image for your reference.How to create those images and how to set those as a background for our Activity or Fragment[image]

In this above image there is yellow and white pattern like shape as a background for this screen.I don't know is it a vector drawable or not.If it is a vector drawable then how to create it and add it as a background for the actiivty or fragment?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, You need to add images-.svg/.png as background for main layout for activity's xml.

Comment: Yeah.we need images.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any images or anything for this. Just create a main layout with the Full screen (match parent basically) and set the colour of that main layout to Yellow or whatever it is in your image.

After that add one more layout in your main layout with the top right corner as per your design with the white background and then create your views in that. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930555/android-drawable-with-rounded-corners-at-the-top-only) is a question which will help you how to get the rounded corners at top not exactly same as you want but I am sure you it'll be of great help to you.